# Getting multiple values with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I am using scanf() to get a set of ints from the user. But I would like the user to supply all 4 ints at once instead of 4 different promps. I know I can get one value by doing:

```
scanf( "%i", &minx);
```

But I would like the user to be able to do something like:

```
Enter Four Ints: 123 234 345 456
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Josh Curren %d converts input as if it is a decimal representation.  %i converts input as if it is a decimal, hexadecimal or octal string using the usual leading 0, 0x, 0X to steer toward octal or hexadecimal.  Example: "010" converts differently.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do this with a single call, like so:

```
scanf( "%i %i %i %i", &minx, &maxx, &miny, &maxy);
```

Comment: you can use %d %i %o %x %X for ints.. http://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Information/LowLevel-Programming/printf-formatting.shtml

Comment: %d is almost identical to %i. They do the same thing in most cases.

Comment: @Chris: under what circumstance does %i not do what %d does?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer - According to my scanf manpage, "%i" reads the int in base 16 if it begins with `0x` and in base 8 if it begins with `0` and base 10 otherwise. "%d" reads in base 10 always. And the Open Group manpage agrees with mine.

Comment: @wrang-wrang: Yes, it should.  Normally, if you'd use a %d, though, unless you expect non-base 10 numeric data entry.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

```
int minx, miny, maxx,maxy;
do {
   printf("enter four integers: ");
} while (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &minx, &miny, &maxx, &maxy)!=4);
```

The loop is just to demonstrate that scanf returns the number of fields succesfully read (or EOF).

Comment: The only trouble with that code is that if the user enters just 1 value, then they have to re-enter all 4 values on the next cycle.

Comment: This will turn into an infinite loop if I enter invalid data(like characters)

Answer (score 7):

```
int a,b,c,d;
if(scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4) {
   //read the 4 integers
} else {
   puts("Error. Please supply 4 integers");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, we can use array as well:

```
int i, array[4];
printf("Enter Four Ints: ");
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do this, but then the user has to separate the numbers by a space:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int minx, x, y, z;

    printf("Enter four ints: ");
    scanf( "%i %i %i %i", &minx, &x, &y, &z);

    printf("You wrote: %i %i %i %i", minx, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: "user has to separate the numbers by a space" is not so.  User input could be "12-34+56-78".

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but if someone could help from this with real-life example.

For Single Input data -

```
int number;
printf("Please enter number : ");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

For Multiple Input data at a line -

```
int number1, number2;
printf("Please enter numbers one by one : ");
scanf("%d %d", &number1, &number2);
```

- `%d %d` is for decimal format. You could use format which is suitable for your data type as many as needs with just a `space`
- `&number1, &number2` - Use `comma` between variable names

If needs More real-life example check this practical example - https://devsenv.com/tutorials/how-to-take-input-and-output-in-c-programming

Hope, this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Passable for getting multiple values with `scanf()`

```
int r,m,v,i,e,k;

scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",&r,&m,&v,&i,&e,&k);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int a[1000] ;
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 3 , i++)
scanf("%d" , &a[i]) ;
```