# How to get multiple input using scanf c

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int birth_year;
    
    printf("Enter your name : ");
    scanf("%c",name);
    
    printf("Enter your birth year : ");
    scanf("%i",&birth_year);
    
    int age = 2020 - birth_year;
    printf("Your age is %i",age);
}
```

I am trying to take the value of birth_year as an input but it automatically assigns it to 0 for some reason what am I doing wrong

Comment: Use `%s` (not `%c`) for a character array (string).

Comment: Duplicated, you can see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412513/getting-multiple-values-with-scanf

Comment: @MiguelGarcía Hmm - not an *obvious* duplicate but I'm sure there is one somewhere. The issue here is reading a single character rather than a string.

Answer (score 2):

In the first scanf you should read a string instead of a char, that should do it.
Also, it's always good to have a whitespace before you read a char, so it resets the buffer memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int birth_year;

    printf("Enter your name : ");
    scanf(" %s",name);

    printf("Enter your birth year : ");
    scanf(" %d",&birth_year);

    int age = 2020 - birth_year;
    printf("Your age is %i",age);
}
```

Comment: Aside `char name[10];` is almost *certain* to overflow. Be sure to use a longer string such as `char name[100];` and restrict the input with `scanf(" %99s",name);`. These two format specifiers automatically filter leading whitespace, it is only really necessary with `%c` and `%[]`, which do not.

Comment: `scanf(" %s",name);` is bad/worse than [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).